# error MT0117: Can't launch a 32-bit app on a simulator that only supports 64-bit apps (iPhone 6s)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ios-simulator

Using Xamarin.Forms, Visual Studio 2017 on a PC, and MacBook Air for building the mobile application to iOS.

Yesterday, I updated the Visual Studio version to 15.3.5. I also updated the MacBook Air (via VS for Mac) to get the latest version of iOS (11.0).
I created a new app (Xamarin.Forms) just to test the update and everything worked as expected.

I tried to run an older app that I was developing previously, and I wasn't able to run it on the Mac.

I got the following error:

```
Launch failed. The app 'AppName.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone 6s iOS 11.0'. 
Error: error MT0117: Can't launch a 32-bit app on a simulator that only supports 64-bit apps (iPhone 6s). Please check the logs for more details.
The app has been terminated.
```

Next, I plugged in a device (iPhone) to the Mac and tried to run the application to the device. I was able to run the application, but I got a message notifying me that the application will stop running as soon as I update the iOS of the Device (I didn't update the iOS on the device).

So, the question is how do I solve the problem? Does this has something to do with my application, or the packages that I'm using? Is there a setting that I need to set? Is it possible to run an old simulator on the Mac?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you change the support architectures to "i386 + x86_64" or "x86_64", it should solve your problem.

You can right click your project -> properties -> iOS build -> change "Supported Architectures" to "i386 + x86_64" or "x86_64"

Comment: The problem was the following. I have created a custom build configuration. While creating the custom configuration, you’re able to copy the settings from an existing. I choose to copy from the Debug since I wanted it for development. It seems that not all the properties of the build configuration are copied! One of the properties that wasn’t copied and in fact it was empty (!) was the “Supported Architectures”. So just by setting the property to a value, I was able to run the application. Your answer pointed out the place to look for finding the solution so  I consider the answer as correct.

Comment: To be noted that if not clear if talking about simulator or VS, it's VS. You can right click your project -> properties -> iOS build -> change "Supported Architectures" to `i386 + x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

With Xcode 9 it should be possible to install simulators back as far as iOS 8.1 - a least that's what the "Components" tab says in the Xcode preferences.

I don't use the simulators regularly since at my company we have a couple of test devices with all our supported iOS versions and i trust testing on actual hardware more than testing on simulators.

Comment: There is a variety of simulators but I think that they all run iOS 11 now after the update. Anyway, changing the version of the simulator is a "patch" that will help me continue the development but the real problem is how to solve the actual error.